# Next-Gen Corda 5.0 - Facing issue while creating CPI file from CPB file

Tags: corda, corda-dlt

I am trying to create CPI file for member virtual node. I have deployed Corda network using Kubernetes scripts provided by R3. As per documentation [https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/5.0/application-networks/creating/members/cpi.html], I am using corda-cli tool for creating member CPI file.

**Command:**

```
./corda-cli.sh package create-cpi --cpb "$WORK_DIR/member-cordapp-cpb.cpb" --group-policy "$WORK_DIR/GroupPolicy.json" --cpi-name member-cordapp-cpi --cpi-version "1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT" --file "$WORK_DIR/member-cordapp-cpi.cpi" --keystore $HOME/memberSigningkeystore.keystore --storepass "password" --key "member-signing-key"
```

**Output:**

```
Error verifying CPB: Trusted certificates not set
```

**Note:**

> In above command, I am using the same signing credentials(keystore, key and password) which I used for creating the CPB file. While creating CPB file[member-cordapp-cpb.cpb], I used keystore[memberSigningkeystore.keystore], signing key[member-signing-key] and password["password"].

I need member CPI file for virtual node creation. I tried using different signing keys and credentials, but still facing the same issue.